# Main para função sobre listas ligadas

Tags: c, funções

Estou com dificuldades para criar um main de modo a testar se a minha função está a correr bem. O meu programa é o seguinte : **LInt fromArray (int v[], int N)**  que, dado um array v com N elementos, ordenado por ordem crescente, constroi uma lista ordenada com os elementos do array, pela mesma ordem. Aqui está o que consegui fazer :

```
typedef struct slist 
{
  int valor;
  struct slist *prox;
} *LInt;

LInt fromArray (int v[], int N)
{
  LInt nova = (LInt)malloc(sizeof (struct slist));
  LInt aponta = nova;
  int i;

  if (N==0) 
  { return NULL; }

  for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
  {
    nova->valor = v[i];
    nova->prox = (LInt)malloc(sizeof (struct slist));
    nova = nova->prox;
  }

   nova = NULL;

   return aponta;
}
```

**Como faço o main para esta função ? E em geral para funções sobre listas ligadas , qual o aspeto principal em ter em conta na criação do main?**

Answer (score 2):

Para acrescentar um elemento no fim duma lista ligada é preciso percorrer toda a lista.
Para acrescentar um elemento no princípio duma lista ligada não é preciso nada de especial.

Para converter um array já ordenado numa lista, sugiro que comeces a adicionar do fim do array para o princípio.

Escrevi um exemplo completo (que tambem podes [ver a correr no ideone](http://ideone.com/BkfDFM)) -- como vês não é preciso nada de especial na função `main()`. Na minha função `list_fromarray()` é preciso sinalizar a lista inicial vazia com NULL (`struct list *li = NULL;`) e usar o endereço do ponteiro ao chamar funções que alterem a lista.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list {
    int value;
    struct list *next;
};

void list_add(struct list **li, int value);
struct list *list_fromarray(int *v, int n);
void list_print(struct list *li, const char *msg);
void list_free(struct list *li);

int main(void) {
    struct list *list;
    int test[] = {1, 4, 8, 9, 13, 42};
    list = list_fromarray(test, sizeof test/sizeof *test);
    list_print(list, "final list");
    list_free(list);
}

struct list *list_fromarray(int *v, int n) {
    struct list *li = NULL;
    for (int k = n - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
        list_add(&li, v[k]);
    }
    return li;
}

void list_add(struct list **li, int value) {
    struct list *node;
    node = malloc(sizeof *node);
    node->value = value;
    node->next = *li;
    *li = node;
}

void list_print(struct list *li, const char *msg) {
    printf("%s:", msg);
    while (li) {
        printf(" %d", li->value);
        li = li->next;
    }
    puts("");
}

void list_free(struct list *li) {
    while (li) {
        struct list *bak = li;
        li = li->next;
        free(bak);
    }
}
```